# How to combine an update and delete in a single sql statement without vialoating index constraints?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, ado.net

Is it somehow possible to execute following sql statement without violating a unique index constraint that ensures that the `Position` is unique?

```
UPDATE wl SET Position = Position - 1 
FROM [dbo].[WatchList] wl 
WHERE Position > ( SELECT Position FROM [dbo].[WatchList] wl2
                   WHERE WatchListId = @WatchListID );
DELETE FROM [dbo].[WatchList] WHERE WatchListID = @WatchListID
```

I want to ensure that no Positon-gaps occur when i delete one record. All records with a higher position should be updated with `Position=Position-1`.

But that will cause a unique index violation because the row is yet not deleted. Are the only ways to prevent this issue to ...

- use a stored-procedure (should be avoided if possible, logic should be in code)
- to determine the old position before i delete the record which requires two queries

Update:

Thanks for your efforts. However, since there is no easy solution for this i have used the second approach, so first determine the old postion, delete the record and then update the followers.

Comment: How will you handle two concurrent sessions that both delete a record simultaneously? What is the background behind the requirement that no gaps should occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run two different (types of) statements, and have constraints maintained both before and after, use `MERGE`:

```
create table T (
    ID int not null,
    Position int not null,
    constraint PK_T_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint UQ_T_ID UNIQUE (Position))

insert into T(ID,Position) values
(12,1),
(22,2),
(36,3),
(47,4)


declare @ToDelete int
set @ToDelete = 22

;With Positions as (
    select
        Position
    from
        T
    where
        Position >= (select Position from T where ID = @ToDelete)
)
merge into T t
using (select Position from Positions) s
on
    t.Position = s.Position
when matched and ID = @ToDelete
then delete
when matched then update set Position = t.Position -1
;
select * from T
```

Results:

```
ID          Position
----------- -----------
12          1
36          2
47          3
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. But i have actually used my second approach which requires more than one query. First determine the old position, delet e the record and then update the followers. Readability matters :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - probably for the best - until the input is a table-variable containing inserts, updates and deletes to apply and you want to show off doing it all in one statement :-)

Answer (score 0):

If Position is the primary key, to cause an index violation, you might be able to make use of ALTER INDEX and do a REBUILD *after* the Delete.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[WatchList] WHERE WatchListID = @WatchListID
ALTER INDEX PK_Watchlist ON dbo.Watchlist REBUILD
```

Comment: Is this efficient and safe? I guess this could be more harmful than just selecting the old position before i delete the record and then updating the following records afterwards. Also, the Position is not the primary key but a column which must be unqiue(actually in combination with another column). The Update-statement violates this constraint.

Comment: Ah.  No this will not work against a normal column, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

But you already have two queries

```
declare @pos int;
set @pos = SELECT Position FROM [dbo].[WatchList] wl2
           WHERE WatchListId = @WatchListID;
DELETE FROM [dbo].[WatchList] WHERE pos = @pos;
UPDATE wl SET Position = Position - 1 
FROM [dbo].[WatchList] wl 
WHERE Position > @pos;
```